# Split Gridview into two part of column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Grid view show in Two part of this in asp.net [image]

I have create one Gridview to show Department name and there no of member but I want to split this gridview and split into two part of gridview with same columns name also.
please give me idea to solve this issue.

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the records using connection (`sqlCn`).

Create a temporary datatable (`dtTemp`)

Fill it using data adapter (`sqlDA`)

Create a new datatable (`dt`)

Add columns (`colA1`, `colB1`, `colA2`, `colB2`)

In a loop, create a datarow (`dr`) and fill its cells with `dtTemp`'s data, then add `dr` to `dt`.

Bind it with datagridview (`DataGridView1`).

```
    SqlConnection sqlCn = new SqlConnection( ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ "myConStr" ].ConnectionString );
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter( "SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table1", sqlCn );
    DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    sqlDA.Fill( dtTemp );

    //Create columns for dt
    dt.Columns.Add( "colA1", typeof( String ) );
    dt.Columns.Add( "colA2", typeof( String ) );
    dt.Columns.Add( "colB1", typeof( String ) );
    dt.Columns.Add( "colB2", typeof( String ) );


    for ( int i = 0; i < dtTemp.Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();//create a new datarow  for dt

        dr["colA1"] = dtTemp.Rows[i]["col1"];
        dr["colA2"] = dtTemp.Rows[i]["col2"];

        i++; //move to next line

        dr["colB1"] = dtTemp.Rows[i]["col1"];
        dr["colB2"] = dtTemp.Rows[i]["col2"];

        dt.Rows.Add( dr );
    }

    //Show the grid 
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: How could this be the answer, when the question (as vague as it is) was I think, asking how to split a column into two

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to do it by standard ASP.Net GridView component. You are able try to do it by two GridViews or some 3rd party component.

Comment: Can I get help of Jquery of using in 3rd party tool? If yes so please give me idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply modify your datasource

get the value in dataset in two tables

order by any column and then get half record order by field asc in first table

order by any column and then get half record order by field desc in first table

just need to write two `select` statements

it will fill the dataset with two tables
then bind `gridview1` with first and `gridview2` with second.